# Service account or OAuth? (authenticate multiple users from a webapp to communicate with Google Compute Engine API)

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-compute-engine

I'm deploying a web app and I'd like to know if it's better to use OAuth or a service account credentials to authenticate multiple users to use multiple instances of Google Compute Engine VMs. I'm deploying a server to server communication to submit a "start" request to the Compute Engine API.

Currently, I'm the only user that the administrator has given access to the Compute Engine project, but the goal is that any of our coworkers who needs it, could get authenticated and access the VM through the web app.

I ask here because I've been reading documentation but I'm still unsure what's the path to take.

I'd appreciate some guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: If the users need to log into a web application and then press a "start" button, you can use many different authentication systems. The simplest is username/password and a file-based user list or possibly one of the OAuth providers. The VM would then call the Compute Engine Start API. However, authorization appears simple, implementing a correct configuration requires some expertise. In your use case, the users would not use a service account unless they actually need to call the API themselves.

Comment: Understood, I managed to configure an OAuth configuration.